# Как спарсить JSON сервера в Java Volley

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, парсер

Как можно спарсить ответ от сервера в Volley get запросе с помощью org.json? В файле содержится информация о категории задачи, а также самих задачах, находящихся в этой категории. Необходимо распарсить названия категорий по двум разным массивам с учётом того, категорий и дочерних задач в ответе будет много. Заранее спасибо.

JSON:

```
{
  "notes": 
  [
    {
      "content": "New category",
      "color": "#64c4ed",
      "childs": [
        {
          "content": "Тест",
          "_id": "5fc145b234f3a7834c1fd17c",
          "parent": "5fc1445134f3a7834c1fd178",
          "date": "2020-11-27T18:30:10.929Z",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ],
      "_id": "5fc1445134f3a7834c1fd178",
      "owner": "5fc142e026e8f14174dc4bad",
      "date": "2020-11-27T18:24:17.000Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "content": "Эййй",
      "color": "#ff6464",
      "childs": [
        {
          "content": "я",
          "_id": "5fc1448434f3a7834c1fd17a",
          "parent": "5fc1447d34f3a7834c1fd179",
          "date": "2020-11-27T18:25:08.625Z",
          "__v": 0
        },
        {
          "content": "Тест2",
          "_id": "5fc1448b34f3a7834c1fd17b",
          "parent": "5fc1447d34f3a7834c1fd179",
          "date": "2020-11-27T18:25:15.954Z",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ],
      "_id": "5fc1447d34f3a7834c1fd179",
      "owner": "5fc142e026e8f14174dc4bad",
      "date": "2020-11-27T18:25:01.000Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Get запрос:

```
private void Submit(final String token, final List<String> categories){

        String URL = "http://localhost/api/note/";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
            {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token);
                return headers;
            }
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType(){return "application/json; charset=utf-8"; }

        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы распарсил Ваш JSON так:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("response");
JSONArray notesJsonArray = object.getJSONArray("notes");
for (int i = 0; i < notesJsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject noteJsonObject = notesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    // куда-то пишем данные из noteJsonObject
    if (noteJsonObject.has("childs")) {
        JSONArray childsJsonArray = notesJsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < childsJsonArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject childsJsonObject = childsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            // куда-то пишем данные из childsJsonObject
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Во втором цикле выдаёт JSONException e - только заметил. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А какой полный текст строки исключения?